# LibreOffice menu bar problem

Tags: libreoffice, fonts, menu-bar, special-characters

Any idea of why does this happen? I don't know why this happened, suddenly it displayed that way. Please see the screenshot below

[image]

I would appreciate any help concerning this issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It was a font issue, I changed the interface font and the problem was gone.

Comment: Can you provide more info eg which font was it set to and which font fixed it?

Comment: And which version of LibreOffice on which version and flavor of Ubuntu?

Comment: The previous font I was using was Myriad Web Pro Regular and I changed it to Nimbus Sans L Regular, but like Ethan said in the comment below the new update fixes this issue.

Comment: The LibreOffice version  was the 5.4.5 running in ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the problem checking "*Use LibreOffice's dialog windows*" (**Dialog windows open/save**) in *Tools->Options->LibreOffice->General*

LibreOffice Version: 5.4.5.1, Build ID: 1:5.4.5-0ubuntu0.17.10.1

Answer (score 1):

It appears that a new update fixes this issue. Running `apt update` and `apt full-upgrade` should resolve it.